# Locked questions cleanup

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, locked-question, clean-up

@MichaelT and I were [discussing the purpose of locked questions last night in chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21732881#21732881) He brought up this post from Meta.SE: [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for/126631#126631)

> When is it appropriate to lock a question for historical reasons?
>
> #### When is it appropriate to lock a question for historical reasons?
>
> Questions can be historically locked when:
>
> 1. The post is Off-Topic or Not Constructive, and
> 2. The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature, and
> 3. There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post, and
> 4. The post is contentious; i.e. it has been closed and reopened at least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once
>
> #### When is it not appropriate to historically-lock a question?
>
> Questions should not be historically locked if they:
>
> 1. Are being actively maintained, or
> 2. Have little or no redeeming value.

With this in mind, I searched for all locked posts. We have [744 locked posts](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes); many of these are good and we should keep around, and is quite a lot of posts especially for what would have to be a moderator only review. Can we do better?

We have [175 posts that match the search `locked:yes views:0..5000 score:0..10 duplicate:no migrated:no`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes+views%3A0..5000+score%3A0..10+duplicate%3Ano+migrated%3Ano). They have low views (so don't help much with SEO), low score, and don't help with searching as merge source questions, and won't disappear on their own when the migration timeout ends. This search results in gems like these ***first** three posts returned under **relevance** sort*:

- [Economy simulation software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/146781/economy-simulation-software)
- [PHP and SQL, together or individually](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80434/php-and-sql-together-or-individually)
- [Providing work experience on my resume](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82342/providing-work-experience-on-my-resume)

I see almost no reason to keep **any** of these 175 posts. They add nothing. If we drop the view threshold to **2000** posts, we are *still left with [142 questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes+views%3A0..2000+score%3A0..10+duplicate%3Ano)*.

### Why should we bother?

@MichaelT said it best last night:

> Consider if that is the type of impression we wish to give to users who are coming into the site about the types of things we have on the site (remember, new users don't know / understand / care about historical locks).

I know that not all of these are historical locks; many (most? all?) of them are rejected migrations. That's no reason to keep them. [**Note that migration rejected stubs never get deleted from the destination site!**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224474/are-rejected-migrations-ever-automatically-deleted-from-the-destination-site-sh)

### Let's get rid of them with fire.

[image: Burn with fire!]

Comment: I flagged a bunch of these after [the discussion in this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256840/are-flags-for-immediate-problems-or-just-problems/256889?noredirect=1#comment837924_256889)

Comment: It should probably be noted that the lock for most of these is because the post got migrated here from another site, and then closed. It gets auto-locked to prevent it from going back to the original site. This is not the same as a historical lock.

Comment: @Rachel "I know that not all of these are historical locks; many (most? all?) of them are rejected migrations. That's no reason to keep them."

Comment: Ah I missed that comment. I'm not sure what deleting a migrated question would do, if anything. I noticed that many of them were deleted at their source site, so it might just do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

[`locked:yes views:0..2000 score:0..3 duplicate:no migrated:no`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes+views%3A0..2000+score%3A0..3+duplicate%3Ano+migrated%3Ano)

After a few days, we should have enough agreement on this batch of 49 questions to move forward with the actions in the below headings.

### The following questions should remain closed but not deleted

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88359/is-the-spark-view-engine-for-asp-net-dead?s=16|0.0000
- [Help me construct a list of best approaches for new C and C++ developers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21032/help-me-construct-a-list-of-best-approaches-for-new-c-and-c-developers?s=43|0.0000)

### The following questions should remain closed, but be unlocked and have their answers undeleted:

- [PCI Compliance with Offshore Development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87385/pci-compliance-with-offshore-development?s=26|0.0000)

### These questions should be deleted:

#### 1 score:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48770/what-are-the-duties-of-a-software-control-management-scm-engineer-in-a-large-c?s=47|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60764/general-tips-on-writing-specs-for-java-programmers?s=42|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87888/what-is-the-proper-name-for-this-design-pattern-in-python?s=41|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30173/about-c-objects-and-the-possibilties-it-has?s=40|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219131/forcing-users-to-use-javascript?s=38|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104232/how-do-you-address-or-avoid-problems-with-new-features-being-quickly-added-to-th?s=35|0.0000

#### 2 score:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66976/how-important-would-a-statistics-course-be-to-a-software-developer?s=32|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42899/could-anyone-suggest-me-some-image-manipulation-techniques-to-be-added-to-my-ima?s=31|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83695/how-can-i-keep-track-of-all-the-websites-ive-made-like-a-proper-business-would?s=29|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80051/practice-programming-guidance?s=25|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75439/how-is-a-net-developer-related-to-customer-relationship-management-crm?s=21|0.0000

#### 3 score:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/software-methodologies?s=20|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94040/what-to-study-at-grad-school-if-i-want-to-know-about-programming-languages?s=19|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38507/what-are-the-most-important-things-to-know-about-iphone-development?s=13|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35052/depending-on-another-open-source-library-copy-paste-code-or-include?s=12|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97555/future-of-soap-with-rest?s=11|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107582/why-would-an-employee-not-be-allowed-to-share-techniques?s=10|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54651/how-to-make-an-app-more-intuitive?s=7|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77447/portfolio-and-nda?s=6|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43464/source-of-programmer-inefficiency?s=5|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70213/teaching-programming-quickly-to-those-adults-that-havent-programmed?s=4|0.0000
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73449/functional-programming-language-for-web-development?s=3|0.0000

Comment: @Mapleshaft for https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/21032/help-me-construct-a-list-of-best-approaches-for-new-c-and-c-developers - lets revisit this in a few months. Since your canonical edit two years ago, the question has only gotten a typo fix. Is there sufficient community behind the question to keep it up to date and useful?

Answer (score 3):

The locked questions that I am particularly (dis)interested in are the ones that were historically locked at some point in the back and *really* haven't aged well. They are relatively low view and vote.

[is:question closed:yes locked:yes duplicate:no migrated:no views:..3000 votes:..20](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ayes+locked%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano+migrated%3Ano+views%3A..3000+votes%3A..20)

Note that this picks up a fair number of rejected migrations too.

This query brings up things such as:

- [Language agnostic programming books](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163/language-agnostic-programming-books) : score of 20, 1242 views, 10 answers of which many of them are *really* poorly written links and one liners.
- [Suggestions for Programs to develop for learning](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/suggestions-for-programs-to-develop-for-learning) : score of 12, 894 views, very poorly written question, 9 answers of which most are a single sentence.
- [Career guidance books for programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/career-guidance-books-for-programmers) : score of 18, 1463 views, 10 answers and it shouldn't be a surprise that I include it here because most are single sentence answers (some not even a sentence)
- [What can slow a developer down?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2192/what-can-slow-a-developer-down) : score of 12, 1606 views, 31 answers (2 deleted), and... yes, mostly single sentence answers.
- [Which language features are considered harmful?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/which-language-features-are-considered-harmful) : score of 20, 2454 views, 32 answers. Mostly single sentence answers.

I hold that these questions (and others) should be closely reexamined with the [criteria from MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/213963).

I do not believe that any of these questions meet the criteria of "The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature" and likely also fail to come close to the criteria of "There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post".  Despite these question being several years old they have not shown that they have the views or the score to warrant permanency.

I believe that these questions should be deleted. If you wish to unlock them first and then have the community delete them, that's certainly an option.  Note that only one of them in this list would require more than three delete votes.

---

After digging a bit on Data.SE [this isn't too big of a list to re-evaluate](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/321872?Views=3000&Score=20) (once you get the migrations, unlocked, and merged questions out of there) it brings up a number of... well,

- [Help me construct a list of best approaches for new C and C++ developers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21032/help-me-construct-a-list-of-best-approaches-for-new-c-and-c-developers) (+1 score, 483 views, wiki lock, last accessed a year ago)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65316/what-are-some-tips-for-avoiding-death-by-powerpoint-during-a-technical-present (+1 score, 956 views with some really not stellar answers)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11757/what-are-good-social-coding-sites (+2 score, 1938 views with answers of "github", "bitbucket" and "bitbucket" and "I have a public svn server")
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141676/recommendable-reads-about-programming-history (+3 score, 539 views, 10 answers of which half don't even take up enough space to line wrap)

These are questions that we are saying have historical significance and are stellar examples (all be it off topic) of what the site wishes to maintain.